# Unable to pull data from android smartwatch using adb - remote object does not exist

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

So I'm attempting to extract data from the LG G smart watch running Android wear. I have rooted this device and am attempt to pull data from a folder within the "Data" file which is "data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/assets/3g".

I do this using the following command sequence:

[image]

However when I attempt to do an adb pull of this location I get the following error:

> remote object "data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/assets/3g" does not exist.

I have tried to change the file permissions of the folder to ensure I have full access to it using the following command:

> chmod 777 data

I am able to see that I have full access to the folder but still I cannot extract the data.

I have attempt to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846576/cannot-adb-pull-database-even-after-chmod-777-on-my-device) and chmod the file itself and also the folder it is contained inside but still is does not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need root access to extract that file, which you did get using su on the shell, but not when pulling using adb pull.
You can fix that by:

- Executing

  adb shell "su -c 'cat filepath'" > file.ext

  That will execute cat with root privilege, so it will read the file and then write it to file.ext. This is a bit of a dirty way, but just as valid.
- Using 'adb root'. This method only works on custom ROMs, as it's disabled by default. You can also enable it by using Chainfire's adb Insecure.
  After you do either of those, execute 'adb root', and then you should be able to pull the file.

Comment: Hi there @Pipe, thanks for the response. I have tried the advised command and have the file.ext but was wondering how I might open that file to view it's context? I have done it on a file called "node.db" which contains Google Mail data. And I have also tried to run the "adb root" command but it provides the same error as above. That must be to not having a custom ROM as you've stated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: file.ext is just a placeholder, there you can put any file name and extension, node.db in your case.

Comment: Ahh brilliant, I changed it to node.db so will now just need to find a way to open that file to read the data easily. Just on a side note, if I have an ext4 file then, do you know of a method to view the data inside of that? The file is meant to be a full backup of the "data" folder from the smartwatch but I'm unable to open it to view. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to open it with any SQLite (I don't know if that's what the app uses tho) editor.

Comment: Sorry, just to reiterate, is the SQLite editor to open the ext4 file? Thanks

Comment: ext is just the file system linux uses, not the file format. But yes, sqlite is used to open .db files that are also made with sqlite

Comment: OK, I understand. But if I have that file on a windows computer and it contains the whole contents of the "data" directory, how would I open that file to view the data? Sorry for the questions, bit of a novice with this :)

Answer (score 0):

`adb pull` follows some security policies. While you could read file content inside Android (like `adb shell cat`) you cannot extract it from some paths, like `/data/app`, etc.

I copied file to sdcard area and then `adb pull` succeeded:

```
adb shell cp /data/app/evil.com-1/base.apk /sdcard/my.apk
adb pull /sdcard/my.apk
```